# Unable to remove class from bootstrap button groups

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted a toggleable button group hence used label and input as input groups. The functionality is such that on clicking the disabled state label the user should see a disabled state alert then disable itself and toggle to make the other button active. I have noticed that Bootstrap adds classes active and focus on the click of the label to make it look active. So i am trying the code to remove this 2 classes but it seems it doesn’ t work as intended.

```
<div id='btnGroupFrequencyCI' class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-custom border-radius-none notnowfeature disabled">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="monthly">Monthly
      </label>
       <label class="btn btn-custom border-radius-none active">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="annual"> Annual
       </label>
</div>

    $("#btnGroupFrequencyCI").on('click', function(){                      
       $(this).find('label.notnowfeature').removeClass('active').prop('active', false);  
       $(this).find('label').not('.notnowfeature').addClass('active').prop('active', true);   
    });
```

Comment: What is the observed result?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of things to comment about this, first one is that Bootstrap triggers "active" class on and off, but it doesn't have a functionality for the "disabled" class one. So you are right that this needs to be triggered via JavaScript.
The other thing is that if you leave only the "active" class without the "disabled" like this (notice I removed the "notnowfeature" class):

```
    <label class="btn btn-custom border-radius-none ">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="monthly">Monthly
    </label>
     <label class="btn btn-custom border-radius-none active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="annual"> Annual
     </label>
```

Then bootstrap will "toggle" the "active" class on and off between the btn-group of labels, but those labels wont have the "disabled" class that you want.

Being that said, you have two options, create a CSS rule for displaying the same styles as the bootstrap "disabled" button by saying something like:

```
    label:not(.active) { 
        /* Put any style you want for the disabled label */ 
        color: red; 
    }
```

Or another option will be using JQuery and adding/ removing the bootstrap classes "disabled/active" (This JavaScript option also works without changing the rest of your code):

```
$("#btnGroupFrequencyCI").on('click', function(){                         
  //Cycle through each label inside #btnGroup and ask if they have those classes
  $(this).find('label').each(function(){            
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $(this).removeClass('disabled');
      $(this).addClass('active');          
    }else{
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('disabled')
    }
  });       
});
```

Note: For this example to work it has to use only one active class, by the way, I removed the other class you used "notnowfeature" which was unnecessary.

Hope this helps!